# TSQL Update Table from Import Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012. I want to update a table from another table:

My query looks like this:

```
UPDATE [MySchema].[Delivery]
SET DeliveryId = (SELECT ID FROM @DeliveryIds)
WHERE PoolId = 1
```

Somehow this  query doesn't work... Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you join Delivery to @DeliveryIds? If so, do that.

Comment: You are missing several pieces of information here.  Where is `@DeliveryIds` defined?  Does it only have one record in it?

Comment: Standard expectations for this question would be an input data set example and an output data set expectation. With parameters it's generally acceptable to provide both values and reasons for how they come about. You need to do more work if you expect this community to solve your problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that @DeliveryIds is TABLE variable defined and populated earlier in your stored procedure.

However, we don't know yet how to join that table against your [Delivery] table.   You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE Delivery
SET DeliveryId = DIDS.ID
FROM @DeliveryIds DIDS
WHERE Delivery.PoolId = 1
    and DIDS.?????  =  Delivery.?????
```

Replace the question marks with whatever columns these two tables join on.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot. Your assumption is right... one question perhaps, what can I do if there are more entries in @DeliveryIds than in Delivery? It only updates 1 entry though.... hmm

Comment: The query will only update the records in the Delivery table that have a matching record in the DeliveryIds table.  (based on the join using the ????? columns.   It is ok if DeliveryIds has more or less records than the Delivery table.